# Why Jersey is not on framework list?

Tags: java, netbeans, frameworks, jersey

I am using NetBeans. I see I can add some frameworks to my project:

- Spring Web MVC
- JavaServer Faces
- Struts 1.3.10
- Hibernate 3.2.5

I don't know this framworks, so probably I don't need them at this moment. What I am using now is Jersey (JAX-RS). Just thinking why the Jersey is not on framework list? Is it valid statement to say "I am using Jersey (JAX-RS) framework"?

Answer (score 0):

Libray is there in Netbeans Enerprise Edition. Otherwise use the loibrary 'restlib

Comment: I know the library is under "Add Library..."->"Jersey 1.13 (JAX-RS)". Why it is not a part of the framework list? Spring, JSF, Struts and Hibernate are in "Add Library..." as well.